# Can 1 Cor. 1:10-13 be interpreted as a Commandment against Cults?

Tags: greek, history, 1-corinthians, historical-interpretation, linguistics

> **Question:** In 1 Cor. 13, is the Early Church's understanding of the Command against "Divisions", pragmatically equivalent to the modern Church's prohibition against "Cults"?

**Notes:**

1. The commandment "to not let there be divisions", (1 Cor 1:10), uses the word "***σχίσματα***/schismata."
2. In this context, "σχίσματα" carries with it a very negative connotation.
3. This implies that "division" is a poor translation choice, in this context--is "cult" more accurate?

> **1 Cor. 1:10-13, NASB -** Now I exhort you, brethren, by the name of our Lord Jesus Christ, that you ***all agree and that there be no divisions among you***, but that you be made complete in the same mind and in the same judgment. 11 For I have been informed concerning you, my brethren, by Chloe’s people, that there are quarrels among you. 12 Now I mean this, that ***each one of you is saying, “I am of Paul,” and “I of Apollos,” and “I of Cephas,” and “I of Christ.”*** 13 Has Christ been divided? Paul was not crucified for you, was he? Or were you baptized in the name of Paul?

Comment: This Q&A on Christianity.SE: [In what different ways is the word “cult” used as a label inside Christianity?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/11532/13677) may be of interest.

Comment: *seems as though it would be the Biblical anti-definition of "Cult"* I don't understand what you're trying to say here. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I removed that statement, finding it a bit confusing myself.  I am simply trying to compare our understanding of "Cult" with the text, or Early Church perception.

Comment: @e.s.kohen but if you are beginning from a later understanding of 'Cult', you are not starting from the text - which could make this off topic. Be sure to remain focused on the text in its original context. The rest of your question would have to be asked elsewhere (i.e. how did the early Church understand the concept of 'Cult' [non-related to this specific passage]?).

Comment: There is no need for further edits. I've removed where the most recent edit goes a little too far to ask a historical question non-related to this text (i.e. not arising naturally from this text). Your questions about church history will have to be asked elsewhere - I recommend [Christianity.SE].

Answer (score 1):

Paul is not defining a cult here, he simply cannot be in the larger context. It would be eisegesis for those who say he is and not exegesis, we must let the text speak. He is clearly speaking to "the church of God, which is at Corinth" (1:2) and, if a cult, then he is saying that a cult is the church, which shatters the modern notion of it.

No, he is dealing with pride IN the church - simple as that. Watch where he goes in chapter 2. It's all about pride in these early passages. In the middle, he makes it clear that where the pride of man is (mans wisdom, human ability to reason, etc.) the cross of Christ is emptied of power. But all glorying is in God and not in man. This is the message. He is taking them from their actions (claiming superiority based on who baptized them or taught them) to their motives (self-glorying born out of pride) to the ultimate outcome (removing of the positive impact of the cross of Christ).

Answer (score -2):

***IF*** 1 Cor 1:10-13 is actually characterizing Cults as an inappropriate devotion to individuals--then the attribution of "Cult", (σχίσματα), would certainly apply Marcion/ism--, Montanism, Donatism, etc*.

> **Possible Answer:** Since "σχίσματα," does carry with it a negative connotation, (as seen in 1 Cor 1:10), this term can be considered analogous with "Cult"; "Sects", (αἱρέσεως), on the other hand, which were distinguished by different doctrines, and did not necessarily have a negative connotation.

Is there substantiating evidence from extant writings, early Church writers?

---

> **The Modern Definition**
>
> - **Merriam-Webster, 3 -** a religion regarded as ***unorthodox*** or spurious; also :  its body of adherents

Analysis under this third definition seems to preclude any finding of "Cult," within Protestant circles, (given Protestantism is "Unorthodox" by definition--especially given topics like the Trinity, Oneness, and Unitarianism).

> - **Merriam-Webster, 5.a -**  ***great devotion to a person***, idea, object, movement, or work (as a film or book); especially :  such devotion regarded as a literary or intellectual fad.

Merriam-Webster's Fifth definition seems to support interpreting 1 Cor 1:10-13's reference to "σχίσματα" as "Cults"--*in this context*.

---

**The Latin word, "Cultus," does not seem to be the right word to translate**

"Cult" seems to originate with the Latin "Cultus."  But in the Latin Vulgate New Testament, this word never seems to be associated with "Divisions," "Heresies," or "Sects."  This implies that the modern Connotation that "Cult" now has, does not originate from the Early Church.

But other words are associated with this context :

---

**Scismata / Following Specific People, (Merriam-Webster, Cult - 5.a):**

> **1 Cor. 1:10, GK -** Παρακαλῶ δὲ ὑμᾶς, ἀδελφοί, διὰ τοῦ ὀνόματος τοῦ κυρίου ἡμῶν Ἰησοῦ χριστοῦ, ἵνα τὸ αὐτὸ λέγητε πάντες, καὶ μὴ ᾖ ἐν ὑμῖν **σχίσματα**, ἦτε δὲ κατηρτισμένοι ἐν τῷ αὐτῷ νοῒ καὶ ἐν τῇ αὐτῇ γνώμῃ.
>
> **1. Cor. 1:10, Latin -** obsecro autem vos fratres per nomen Domini nostri Iesu Christi ut id ipsum dicatis omnes et non sint in vobis **scismata** sitis autem perfecti in eodem sensu et in eadem sententia
>
> **1 Cor. 1:10-11, NASB -** Now I exhort you, brethren, by the name of our Lord Jesus Christ, that you all agree and that there be no **divisions** among you,
>
> **1 Cor. 1:11-12, NASB -** For I have been informed concerning you, my brethren, by Chloe’s people, that there are quarrels among you. Now I mean this, that each one of you is saying, **“I am of Paul,” and “I of Apollos,” and “I of Cephas,” and “I of Christ.”**

---

**References to Sects/"Heresies" as Sects/Divisions:**

Notably in these contexts, the word "αἵρεσις", (sects/heresies, doesn't carry a "pejorative connotation," (Christianity is considered a Sect ...).

**Sadducean as a Sect/Heresy:**

> **Acts 5:17  -** Ἀναστὰς δὲ ὁ ἀρχιερεὺς καὶ πάντες οἱ σὺν αὐτῷ― ἡ οὖσα **αἵρεσις τῶν Σαδδουκαίων**― ἐπλήσθησαν ζήλου,

**Pharasaic as a Sect/Heresy:**

> **Acts 15:5  -** Ἐξανέστησαν δέ τινες τῶν ἀπὸ τῆς **αἱρέσεως τῶν Φαρισαίων** πεπιστευκότες, λέγοντες ὅτι Δεῖ περιτέμνειν αὐτούς, παραγγέλλειν τε τηρεῖν τὸν νόμον Μωϋσέως.

**Nazarenes as a Sect/Heresy:**

> **Acts 24:5, GK -** Εὑρόντες γὰρ τὸν ἄνδρα τοῦτον λοιμόν, καὶ κινοῦντα στάσιν πᾶσιν τοῖς Ἰουδαίοις τοῖς κατὰ τὴν οἰκουμένην, πρωτοστάτην τε τῆς τῶν **Ναζωραίων αἱρέσεως**·
>
> **Acts 24:5, Latin -** invenimus hunc hominem pestiferum et concitantem seditiones omnibus Iudaeis in universo orbe et auctorem seditionis sectae Nazarenorum

**Christianity as a Heresy/Sect:**

> **Acts 28:22 -** Ἀξιοῦμεν δὲ παρὰ σοῦ ἀκοῦσαι ἃ φρονεῖς· περὶ μὲν γὰρ **τῆς αἱρέσεως** ταύτης γνωστόν ἐστιν ἡμῖν ὅτι πανταχοῦ ἀντιλέγεται.
>
> **Acts 28:22, NASB -** But we desire to hear from you what your views are; for concerning this **sect**, it is known to us that it is spoken against everywhere.”

**Other Instances:**

> **1 Cor. 11:19, Latin -** nam oportet et **hereses** esse ut et qui probati sunt manifesti fiant in vobis
>
> **1 Cor. 11:19, GK -** Δεῖ γὰρ καὶ **αἱρέσεις** ἐν ὑμῖν εἴναι, ἵνα οἱ δόκιμοι φανεροὶ γένωνται ἐν ὑμῖν.
>
> **1 Cor. 11:19, NASB -** For there must also be **factions** among you, so that those who are approved may become evident among you.
>
> **Gal. 5:20, GK -** εἰδωλολατρεία, φαρμακεία, ἔχθραι, ἔρεις, ζῆλοι, θυμοί, ἐριθεῖαι, διχοστασίαι, **αἱρέσεις**,
>
> **2 Peter 2:1, GK -** Ἐγένοντο δὲ καὶ ψευδοπροφῆται ἐν τῷ λαῷ, ὡς καὶ ἐν ὑμῖν ἔσονται ψευδοδιδάσκαλοι, οἵτινες παρεισάξουσιν **αἱρέσεις** ἀπωλείας, καὶ τὸν ἀγοράσαντα αὐτοὺς δεσπότην ἀρνούμενοι, ἐπάγοντες ἑαυτοῖς ταχινὴν ἀπώλειαν.